# Cannot get a java app to run/start as a service using systemd

Tags: linux, java, centos7, systemd

I am trying to get a java app(server) to start as a service using systemd on my Centos 7 but it always fails.

this is my push.service

```
[Unit]
Description=b4xpush server
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -jar /home/mike/push/PushServer.jar
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

after creating the file, I start by using

```
sudo systemctl start Push.service
```

but in vain...

The java app will run fine if I run it manually:

```
/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -jar /home/mike/push/PushServer.jar
```

or

```
java -jar /home/mike/push/PushServer.jar
```

How can I get it running? The ultimate goal is to get it start when the server boots.

Could it be a permission error? When I try to create this I'm logged in as mike and I have "sudo" rights. The app (jarfile) is located in my home-folder as you can see in above service-file.

I have tried everything I can think of but I cannot resolve it and get it to work. Any ideas?

Edit:
Added log file using status:

```
[mike@vps ~]$ sudo systemctl status Push.service -l
Push.service - b4xpush server
   Loaded: loaded (/etc/systemd/system/Push.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: start-limit) since Thu 2015-11-12 16:20:52 CET; 1min 25s ago
  Process: 3651 ExecStart=/usr/java/jdk1.8.0_45/bin/java -jar /home/mike/push/PushServer.jar (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 3651 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com java[3651]: at anywheresoftware.b4a.BA.raiseEvent(BA.java:84)
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com java[3651]: at b4j.example.main.main(main.java:29)
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Push.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Unit Push.service entered failed state.
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Push.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Stopping b4xpush server...
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Starting b4xpush server...
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Push.service start request repeated too quickly, refusing to start.
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Failed to start b4xpush server.
Nov 12 16:20:52 vps.server.com systemd[1]: Unit Push.service entered failed state.
[mike@vps ~]$
```

Comment: Can you post the log of the failure please ? That would help understanding why this fails

Comment: OK, log file from status command added. It works on its owns but not when trying to start it as a service

Comment: You need to look at the complete log, not just the last few lines.

Comment: Is it when the server starts ? or is it when you manually start the service ? It could be starting too soon and the network is not ready yet.

Comment: @pat: when I manually start the service. First I'd like to see it working by starting it manually and once it is fine, I would try it on reboot

Comment: @Michael: where would I get the complete logs?

Comment: From the log files? Or try `journalctl -u Push`

Comment: journalctl does not provide any logs. Had a look at the 'messages' log but it is simply showing the same log-entries as the ones I posted

Comment: tried to do everything logged in as 'root' but no luck...

Comment: Did you try setting the working directory in the service definition?